# Where does respository resides in after converting CVS repository into SVN using cvs2svn?

Tags: cvs2svn

I am using cvs2svn for converting already existing CVS repository into svn repository. While doing it using command line , it makes all the passes and creates a repository in the SVN. But i am not able to find all the files in the particular  directory. Where does that repository resides?

I used following command to convert the CVS to SVN repository.

```
cvs2svn -s /home/user/Subversion/repos /home/usr/cvsrepo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -s option tells cvs2svn where to place the Subversion repository.  This is the database holding your whole project's history; i.e., the part that you might want to put on a central server.  To actually work on the files, you need to check the files out of the repository into a working copy.  To do so, use the following command:

```
svn checkout file:///home/user/Subversion/repos/trunk myproject
```

After that, the directory "myproject" (in the current directory) will contain a checked-out version of the "trunk" (a.k.a., CVS "HEAD") revision of your project.  For more information about how to work with Subversion, see [the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 1):

How are you looking for your files? Don't use `ls`. Instead do a `svn checkout` of that repo and you should find your files in your newly checked out working copy.

Comment: i chekched out using the command 

     svn co file:///path/to/repository 

it shows the list of files being cheked out . but i still could not find the files in the SVN repository that i have migrated from CVS repository.